# manipulation of lists and dictionaries

Tags: python, list, dictionary

This site has helping me a lot. Thank you!
I have a question I would like to resolve.
I have a list of dictionaries, like the one below.

```
[{'time': 98000, 'leader': 0, 'vision': 1},
{'time': 98000, 'leader': 1, 'vision': 0},
{'time': 99000, 'leader': 0, 'vision': 1},
{'time': 99000, 'leader': 0, 'vision': 2},
{'time': 99000, 'leader': 1, 'vision': 0},
{'time': 99000, 'leader': 1, 'vision': 2},
{'time': 99000, 'leader': 2, 'vision': 1},
{'time': 99000, 'leader': 2, 'vision': 0}]
```

I need to find the following matches:

{'time': 98000, 'leader': 0, 'vision': 1} = = {'time': 98000, 'leader': 1, 'vision': 0}`OK
...`
{'time': 99000, 'leader': 2, 'vision': 1} = = {'time': 99000, 'leader': 1, 'vision': 2`} OK
and so on

When the 'leader' value is 0, I want to identify, within the specified time (for example 'time': 99000), if there is any other line where the 'vision' value: is 0. When I find it, I I want to know if the value of the 'leader': of this line is equal to the value of 'vision': of the 'leader': 0. I will follow the same logic for other values of leaders, at different times.

best wishes

Comment: It is not really clear what you mean. You want to loop through all the items and find matches? Why is {'time': 98000, 'leader': 0, 'vision': 1} = = {'time': 98000, 'leader': 1, 'vision': 0}` 
"OK" ?

Comment: Could you elaborate please? Are you looking for equal values of time? or checking all attributes (time, leader, vision)?

Comment: Convert dictionaries to strings. Start new dictionary with strings as key and count as data. When done, filter on count > 1.

Comment: When the 'leader' value is 0, I want to identify, within the specified time (for example 'time': 99000), if there is any other line where the 'vision' value: is 0. When I find it, I I want to know if the value of the 'leader': of this line is equal to the value of 'vision': of the 'leader': 0.

I will follow the same logic for other values of leaders, at different times.

Comment: That sounds kinda complicated and you probably need nested ifs. You can loop through the array `for d in a:` then access dictionary values by keys. `d[key]`. Also a comparison is `if a == b`, no space between the two `=`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, your best bet will to be loop through the list and verify with the `in` operator, which can be done relatively cleanly with list comprehension:

```
def not_unique(el):
    print(el, "has a reciprocal")

def unique(el):
    print(el, "is unique")

tlv_list = [{'time': 98000, 'leader': 0, 'vision': 1},
            {'time': 98000, 'leader': 1, 'vision': 0},
            {'time': 99000, 'leader': 0, 'vision': 1},
            {'time': 99000, 'leader': 0, 'vision': 2},
            {'time': 99000, 'leader': 1, 'vision': 0},
            {'time': 99000, 'leader': 1, 'vision': 2},
            {'time': 99000, 'leader': 2, 'vision': 1},
            {'time': 99000, 'leader': 2, 'vision': 0}]

[not_unique(i) if {'time': i['time'], 'leader': i['vision'], 'vision': i['leader']} in tlv_list else unique(i) for i in tlv_list]
```

Comment: you saved my life!!!

Thanks, Jacob!!!!